# How would you take data from jTextField and add it back to an array?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jtextfield

I want to take a value from a jTextField and add it back to an array. It does not need to be permanently stored. I read hard coded data from this array and output it to a jList and jTextFields. If I wanted to edit this data and save it, how would I do it? I don't not have any code for this as I have no idea where to start. I have searched endlessly online, but nothing I have found makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

UPDATED!! with code.

All of my ArrayLists, created in main class.

```
public static ArrayList<Vol_Observer> volObserver = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Pro_Observer> proObserver = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Animal> animalDetails = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> watchList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Class that has most details.

```
public class Observers 
{  
public String firstName;
public String surname;
public String hNum;
public String streetName;
public String city;
public String county;
public String postcode;
public String email;
public String telNum;

public Observers(String firstName, String surname, String hNum, String streetName, String city, String county, String postcode, String email, String telNum)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.hNum = hNum;
    this.streetName = streetName;
    this.city = city;
    this.county = county;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.email = email;
    this.telNum = telNum;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) 
{
    this.surname = surname;
}

public void sethNum(String hNum) 
{
    this.hNum = hNum;
}

public void setStreetName(String streetName) 
{
    this.streetName = streetName;
}

public void setCity(String city)
{
    this.city = city;
}

public void setCounty(String county)
{
    this.county = county;
}

public void setPostcode(String postcode)
{
    this.postcode = postcode;
}

public void setEmail(String email)
{
    this.email = email;
}

public void setTelNum(String telNum)
{
    this.telNum = telNum;
}

public String getFirstName() 
{
    return firstName;
}

public String getSurname() 
{
    return surname;
}

public String gethNum() 
{
    return hNum;
}

public String getStreetName() 
{
    return streetName;
}

public String getCity()
{
    return city;
}

public String getCounty()
{
    return county;
}

public String getPostcode()
{
    return postcode;
}

public String getEmail()
{
    return email;
}

public String getTelNum() 
{
    return telNum;
}
}
```

Class that extends from the one above, has certain other details.

```
public class Pro_Observer extends Observers
{
public String startDate;
public String endDate;
public String Salary;
public String numObservations;

public Pro_Observer(String firstName, String surname, String hNum, String streetName, String city, String county, String postcode, String email, String telNum, String startDate, String endDate, String Salary, String numObservations) 
{
    super(firstName, surname, hNum, streetName, city, county, postcode, email, telNum);
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.Salary = Salary;
    this.numObservations = numObservations;
}

public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public String getSalary() {
    return Salary;
}

public String getNumObservations() {
    return numObservations;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public void setSalary(String Salary) {
    this.Salary = Salary;
}

public void setNumObservations(String numObservations) {
    this.numObservations = numObservations;
}
}
```

This is the method, so when I click on this button, the application should save the data entered in the jTextField into the ArrayList. I have a jRadioButton that selects something, this is required, so unless it cannot work, please ignore this piece of code.

```
private void addSavejButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            

    if(addVoljRadioButton.isSelected())
    {
        BWA.volObserver.add(addFirstNamejTextField.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show *some* code, pertinent code, if only to make your question more specific and your problem more understandable. Come on, give it a try as you've nothing to lose from the effort. As for "no idea where to start", start with your problem, break it down into its constituent steps, and then try to solve each small step, one at a time until you've come upon a solution or you've hit a roadblock.

Comment: You should take text from `JTextField` with the help of so called "getter". For text it is a method with name `getText()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--. When browsing javadocs, pay special attentions to methods, whose names start with `get` and `set` -- they are getters and setters. Also note that Java has so called "inheritance". This means that methods can be defined inside class ancestors (superclasses, like `JTextComponent` for `JTextField`) -- browse special sections in javadoc too.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have updated the question with my code in there now. I have 2 classes, one that extends another, and the mouse button clicked even handler, where I want the action to be performed.

Comment: @SuzanCioc I have the getters and setters (see above). I would have thought it would be simple to add text to an arraylist, something similar to: `ArrayList.add(jTextField.getText());` but apparently my program does not want to work using that code. I am seriously stuck on how to get past this. Please help, ANYONE!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not very clear on just where you're stuck, but I'll take a guess, perhaps your problem is that you're not able to construct the object of interest in your button handler. If that's the case, I'll try to provide an answer. If that's not the case, then please as we've been requesting, please provide more clear information and more code. Also, when posting code, try to simplify it by removing extra stuff that does not relate to your problem. For instance make a new Observers class just for this question that has just 2 or 3 fields, as the whole complement of fields is not necessary. And also provide some GUI code. You're posting bits and pieces of code, but not enough for us to get a clear picture of what's going on.

For instance, here is a SimpleObserver:

```
class SimpleObserver {
   private String firstName;
   private String surName;
   private String hNum;

   public SimpleObserver(String firstName, String surName, String hNum) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.surName = surName;
      this.hNum = hNum;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public String getSurname() {
      return surName;
   }

   public String gethNum() {
      return hNum;
   }

}
```

Note that fields should be private, not public since one of the main benefits of Java OOPs programming is that it helps reduce complexity of a program partially by allowing you to limit the possible connections between classes, and data hiding is one way of doing this.

Immediate improvements to this class include giving it an equals and a hashCode methods.

Next a simple GUI to display input fields and the JList:

```
class SimpleGui extends JPanel {
   public static final int COLS = 8;
   private DefaultListModel<SimpleObserver> simpleObsListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<SimpleObserver> simpleObsList = new JList<>(simpleObsListModel);
   private JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField(COLS);
   private JTextField surNameField = new JTextField(COLS);
   private JTextField hNumField = new JTextField(COLS);

   public SimpleGui() {
      simpleObsList.setVisibleRowCount(8);
      simpleObsList.setCellRenderer(new SimpleObsListRenderer());
      simpleObsList.setPrototypeCellValue(new SimpleObserver("Big First Name", "Big Last Name", ""));

      // very simple GUI layout
      add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
      add(firstNameField);
      add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
      add(surNameField);
      add(new JLabel("House Number:"));
      add(hNumField);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(simpleObsList);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      add(new JButton(new SubmitAction()));
      add(scrollPane);

   }

   private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {
      public SubmitAction() {
         super("Submit");
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
         // gather data from your fields
         String firstName = firstNameField.getText();
         String surName = surNameField.getText();
         String hNum = hNumField.getText();

         // create your SimpleObserver object here
         SimpleObserver simpleObserver = new SimpleObserver(firstName, surName, hNum);

         // add to JList's model
         simpleObsListModel.addElement(simpleObserver);
      };
   }
}

class SimpleObsListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
         int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      if (value == null) {
         value = "";
      } else {
         SimpleObserver simpleObserver = (SimpleObserver)value;
         String surName = simpleObserver.getSurname();
         String firstName = simpleObserver.getFirstName();
         String display = String.format("%s, %s", surName, firstName);
         value = display;
      }
      return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
            cellHasFocus);
   }
}
```

The key in this code is the AbstractAction class, SubmitAction. This acts as the JButton's ActionListener on steroids since it also sets the button's text, actionCommand, and more. The class simply gathers the Strings held by the GUI's JTextFields, creates a SimpleObserver object, and then places the newly created object into a JList's model.

I've given the JList a cell renderer, but this isn't needed if you give SimpleObject a `toString()` method override that can be used to render it to the list.

The whole working program looks like:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestSimpleObserverGui {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleGui mainPanel = new SimpleGui();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Gui");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SimpleGui extends JPanel {
   public static final int COLS = 8;
   private DefaultListModel<SimpleObserver> simpleObsListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<SimpleObserver> simpleObsList = new JList<>(simpleObsListModel);
   private JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField(COLS);
   private JTextField surNameField = new JTextField(COLS);
   private JTextField hNumField = new JTextField(COLS);

   public SimpleGui() {
      simpleObsList.setVisibleRowCount(8);
      simpleObsList.setCellRenderer(new SimpleObsListRenderer());
      simpleObsList.setPrototypeCellValue(new SimpleObserver("Big First Name", "Big Last Name", ""));

      // very simple GUI layout
      add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
      add(firstNameField);
      add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
      add(surNameField);
      add(new JLabel("House Number:"));
      add(hNumField);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(simpleObsList);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      add(new JButton(new SubmitAction()));
      add(scrollPane);

   }

   private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {
      public SubmitAction() {
         super("Submit");
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
         // gather data from your fields
         String firstName = firstNameField.getText();
         String surName = surNameField.getText();
         String hNum = hNumField.getText();

         // create your SimpleObserver object here
         SimpleObserver simpleObserver = new SimpleObserver(firstName, surName, hNum);

         // add to JList's model
         simpleObsListModel.addElement(simpleObserver);
      };
   }
}

class SimpleObsListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
         int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      if (value == null) {
         value = "";
      } else {
         SimpleObserver simpleObserver = (SimpleObserver)value;
         String surName = simpleObserver.getSurname();
         String firstName = simpleObserver.getFirstName();
         String display = String.format("%s, %s", surName, firstName);
         value = display;
      }
      return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
            cellHasFocus);
   }
}


class SimpleObserver {
   private String firstName;
   private String surName;
   private String hNum;

   public SimpleObserver(String firstName, String surName, String hNum) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.surName = surName;
      this.hNum = hNum;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public String getSurname() {
      return surName;
   }

   public String gethNum() {
      return hNum;
   }

}
```

Regarding your code -- you appear to be heavily using static fields, and I advise against this, so that your program complies with OOP principles, again to reduce complexity and to make debugging and enhancing easier to do.

Note that I've not included ArrayLists since I still have no clue as to what your requirement for this involves. Again, if this doesn't answer your question, then please **improve your question**. Ask it with our point of view in mind: folks who have absolutely no clue as to what your requirements are or what you're trying to do, or what your code looks like, unless you tell us or show us.